# Format time in Typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, time, date-pipe

I want to iterate `time` in my `FormArray` and I'm receiving time from API in the below format:

```
14.21.00
```

I want to format this time like this:

```
2:21 PM
```

I'm trying to format using Angular `DatePipe` like this:

```
{{summon.value.summonTime | date :'shortTime' }}
```

but got error:

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "14.21.00" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

here I reproduced in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udvmad?file=src%2Fapp%2Finquiry-response%2Finquiry-response.component.html)

based on my research, `14.21.00` are not supported time format in javascript/typescript, if there any guidance and suggestion to solve this.

Comment: if its only to display formatted, you can do this: `{{summon.value.summonTime.split('.').join(':')}}`

Comment: but still got error when using `DatePIpe`

Comment: remove date pipe

Comment: my mistakes, updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Try this (tested on your stackblitz code):

```
time:{{'1990-10-10 '+ summon.value.summonTime.split('.').join(':') | date:'shortTime' }}
```

To use the "date" pipe, time must follow a date too, so we can pass any date just to validate the date pipe. For example, this works: {{'1990-10-10 01:02:03' | date:'shortTime'}}, and this does not works: {{'01:02:03' | date:'shortTime'}}.

Also I have replaced the "." (dots) on time with ":" with split and join to take formatted as needed.

Comment: hi mate, it seems work, any explanation for you answer ?

Comment: Yes, I have editted the answer with explanation. Good vibes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope You're doing great!!!

Create a New Pipe in the folder you wish. Once done, please provide details in the module (import and declaration): -

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateTransformer'
})
export class DateTransformerPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value && value.length > 0 ? value.replace('.', ':') : value;
  }
}
```

Once done, update this in your snippet: -

```
<ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked" />
  {{ summon.value.summonTime | dateTransformer }}
  item: {{ summon.value.itemNo }}
  <br />
  time:{{ summon.value.summonTime | dateTransformer }}
  <br />
</ng-container>
```

Hope, I was able to resolve your query! Happy Coding!! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngx-moment` as below

```
{{summon.value.summonTime | amParse:'HH.mm.ss' | amDateFormat:'hh:mm a'}}
```

see your modified stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-pipe-2324234

Comment: thanks, but if there any way without angular library ?

Comment: you can develop you own pipe, reading values separate by `.` and convert 24 hrs to 12 hours, and add am/pm